# How to select all the stored procedures from Oracle database with one statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I want to view **all** the stored procedure implementations owned by `fooUser` in an Oracle database.

By using `rownum`, I am able to do this for the first procedure in `dba_objects` table, but there are many procedures in `dba_objects` table owned by *fooUser*.

I do not want to write a stored procedure to achieve this, I want to do this with one SQL statement.

Query to get the first stored procedure implementation:

```
SELECT 
    line, text
FROM 
    dba_source
WHERE
    name = (SELECT object_name 
            FROM dba_objects 
            WHERE object_type = 'PROCEDURE' 
              AND owner = 'fooUser' AND rownum = 1) 
    AND type = 'PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY 
    line
```

Answer (score 1):

to get source of procedure you can use `dbms_metadata.get_ddl`

see documentation here [dbms_metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#BGBBIEGA)

for example script below returns you list of procedures and source for each procedure where owner is `usr1`

```
select object_name
     , dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type,object_name) from dba_procedures
  where owner = 'USR1'
    and object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

OR

if you need just line-by-line text for all procedures

```
SELECT line, text
FROM dba_source
WHERE owner = 'SCM'
  AND type = 'PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY name, line
```

Comment: I get `ORA-00904: : invalid identifier` on `dbms_metadata`. I do not want to install any package on this DB, just want a native Oracle solution.

Comment: this is standard oracle package since at least 10g version. add permission to your user: `grant execute on dbms_metadata to my_user`

Comment: When I attempt to grant permission I get error `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`. I am running Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: it looks that the user doesn't have permissions to `dba_procedures` and `dbms_metadata` try to connect as `sys` user

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT line, text
FROM dba_source
WHERE owner = ?
  AND name = ?
  AND type = 'PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY line
```

update #1:

```
SELECT line, text
FROM dba_source
WHERE owner = 'foouser'
  AND type = 'PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY line
```

update #2:

```
   SELECT line, text, name
    FROM dba_source
    WHERE owner = 'foouser'
      AND type = 'PROCEDURE'
    ORDER BY name, line
```

Comment: That is what I am doing, so that's why it works for 1 stored procedure (I replaced your 2nd ? with a `select` statement on `dba_objects` and removed your first ? because not required). I need ALL the stored procedure implementations that are in `dba_objects` owned by _fooUser_

Comment: I'm a bit confused on why you require the subselect?  all procedures should be returned if they are owned by foouser.  I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: When I run your update #1, since I am ordering by line, I get line 1 from all the Stored Procedures, then line 2 from all the stored procedures. I need the first entire SP, then the 2nd entire SP.... That's why i thought a subselect is required.